# How app is noticed turning off a auto-renewing subscriptions from Settings > iTunes & App Store menu?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

I'm using In-App Purchase as Auto-Renewable on my app.

There is 2 plans (For example: Plan A and Plan B) of Auto-Renewable, they are different family.
And user must not purchase 2 plans at same time.
If user select subscribe Plan B when using Plan A, I will dialog "Please turn off Auto-renewing Plan A from Settings > iTunes & App Store menu".

But I can't find that how to know user turning off or not.
Is there way to know this?

Comment: If the user "cancels" the subscription they are actually cancelling the automatic renewal, so you will not get a new subscription transaction at the end of the current period, so if the user cannot have two subscriptions active at once you need to wait until the current subscription expires.  By the way you can open the url https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/manageSubscriptions to put the user directly into the subscription management interface

Comment: I understand app will be noticed that is turned off Auto-renewing at end of subscription period.
But, I want to know to be turned off Auto-renewing by user in subscription period.
Is there way?

Comment: No, there is no way.  Once a subscription is purchased the only time you will receive notice of cancellation is if Apple customer support cancel the subscription at customer request (incorrect purchase, fraud etc)